# SpringBoot Application in QA server not invoking endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am working on a SpringBoot application and exposed a rest endpoint for GET method. I am able to invoke the endpoint in my local environment by hitting "localhost:8080/endpoint" or by using curl "http://localhost:8080/endpoint" but I am not able to invoke the same endpoint in QA environment by using the ip address of the instance instead of localhost. Even logged into the VM and tried curl "http://localhost:8080", getting a curl connection refused error. According to my understanding the embedded tomcat server should start at port 8080. Am I missing something related to tomcat configuration?

Comment: Do you have a firewall in the UAT server? If so, ensure that incoming traffic into port 8080 on that server is allowed.

Comment: Check if `server.port` has been set to any other value in the application.properties file in your uat server.